# Crashlytics missing some custom logs

Tags: android, crashlytics

I'm using Crashlytics for crash reporting of my Android app. So far, it's working mostly good except with issue. The one critical issue is that it's missing a few custom logs before the statement where app crash occurred. I want to ask that if there is any mechanism to flush the logs or any other approach to get all the logs reported?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This might be one possible of not getting few custom logs.. 
So what `Crashlytics` doc say is

> Note: By default, Crashlytics currently supports a **maximum of 64 key/value pairs**. Once you reach this threshold, additional values are not saved. If you need more, please contact Support.

visit [Crashlytics Custom Logs](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/120055-how-do-i-use-custom-keys-)